# Visual studio 2010 project for windows and linux

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a program that works on linux and windows.
I'm writing the program in visual studio in a windows environment.

So I wonder how I could compile my project from visual studio to linux.

Comment: You can usually run windows binaries through wine on Linux without trouble, if you want the fast way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft C++ compiler is not capable of producing Linux executables.

You will need to use a more portable compiler for your Linux executables, e.g. gcc. Perhaps you may benefit from a cross-platform IDE like Code Blocks or Eclipse rather than Visual Studio.

Comment: the OP is *not* asking about getting VS to work in/on Linux. The OP is asking how to *compile* a c++ program to work in Linux

Comment: @Eonasdan Well, you can't do that in Visual Studio, or do you know different. Do you disagree with the suggestion of using gcc?

Comment: I don't disagree with the gcc part of your answer. However, both answers (yours and the one deleted) stated that VS wouldn't run on Linux, which isn't what the OP was asking. That's all I was trying to point out, in case you read the question incorrectly. Carry on :)

Comment: @Eonasdan Well, fair enough. If MSVC were a cross compiler then it would be different.

Answer (score 1):

You should try QT. It is pretty good framework for cross-platform development. The opensource version is free and very well maintained and has the LGPL license. That means you can sell your product as closed source but then you have to dynamically link to QT libraries.

Comment: Welcome on SO, it is a good practice to link your sources, so the community can have a look on the original post if they want more informations. :) I also suggest that you have a look to our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). It will allow you to generate project/solution files for Visual Studio and Makefiles for Linux. This way, you can work using the native tool chain for a platform, while managing a single makefile. However, it's up to you to write portable code and to choose the appropriate libraries for your program to be truly portable.